# GoogleMaps A to B from GeoLocate

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good morning together, is there an example / tutorial of how to solve the following problem?
I have 2 addresses, e.g. "Paris, France" and "London, UK". Now I want to get the LatLong with GeoLocate, put a Marker each and draw a line between both with a curve depending on the radius of the world. So like a flight route, which is not straight linear as the globe is a sphere.
Can you please help me?

Edit: Possibly it would be nice if I could also load all of the Google Initiate Stuff only when CLICKING a link so a DIV shows (the div is not display: none; its, position absolute in -10000px left -10000px top to prevent Google Maps issues)

Comment: What does the line represent? Great circle route? If so, it may not be curved depending on the map projection and orientation of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `google.maps.Polyline` [class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline) to draw the line. If you set the `geodesic` [property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolylineOptions) of the `google.maps.PolylineOptions` object to `true` it will follow the great circle route, which I think it what you're asking for.